# Extracting a dashed string between two underscores

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to extract a string with pandas from the following example:

```
print(table)
                FirstColumn                                       SecondColumn                                           
0                    Access    SomeRandomString_wanted-string_edbf4c5de7cdc38b
```

I'm trying to get the `wanted-string` from the tables SecondColumn. I tried using `str.extract` and `str.split` but am not getting the desired output because of the mix of dashes and underscores.

Desired output:

```
print(table)
                FirstColumn          SecondColumn                                           
0                    Access         wanted-string
```

If there's a better way to get the desired string other than using extract or split I'd also appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: What is your extract/ split solution which failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values between `_`:

```
df['SecondColumn'] = df['SecondColumn'].str.extract('_(.*)_')
print (df)
  FirstColumn   SecondColumn
0      Access  wanted-string
```

If need also test `-` between 2 words:

```
df['SecondColumn'] = df['SecondColumn'].str.extract('_(\w+-\w+)_')
print (df)
  FirstColumn   SecondColumn
0      Access  wanted-string
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Accepting when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
df['SecondColumn'].str.split('_')[1]
```